# xNet.dll как добавить header?

Tags: c#, http, xnet

Как добавить Header Content.Type?

Это работает:

```
request.AddHeader(HttpHeader.AcceptLanguage, "ru-RU,en,*");
```

А эта строка генерирует исключение "Значение заголовка 'Content-Type' можно задать только с помощью специального свойства":

```
request.AddHeader(HttpHeader.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заголовок Content-Type (а также Accept-Encoding, Content-Length, Connection, Proxy-Connection, Host) задается непосредственно при вызове метода `Post`:

```
public HttpResponse Post(string address, string str, string contentType)

public HttpResponse Post(Uri address, string str, string contentType)

public HttpResponse Post(string address, byte[] bytes, string contentType = "application/octet-stream")

public HttpResponse Post(Uri address, byte[] bytes, string contentType = "application/octet-stream")

public HttpResponse Post(string address, Stream stream, string contentType = "application/octet-stream")

public HttpResponse Post(Uri address, Stream stream, string contentType = "application/octet-stream")
```

Если что, читайте [исходники](https://github.com/X-rus/xNet/blob/e52879b3bb2d370c1f1d0a256077ad879f2d0477/xNet/~Http/HttpRequest.cs).